# Iphone how to draw Ellipses and other shapes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, shapes

I am new to iphone developement. I have some experience in .net. I am trying to make an app for iphone and am trying to figure out a way to draw different shapes like ellipse, polygons etc. I was wondering if ios has an easy way of doing so like .net (Using `ellipse` and `polygon` class). Thank you

Comment: `QuartzCore.framework`: `CGContextAddEllipseInRect(...)` or `CGContextFillEllipseInRect(...)`; `CGMutablePathRef`, `CGContextAddPath(...)`, `CGContextFillPath(...)`... that is the the way you need to walk through., here is the docs where you can start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

This might be Useful to you :

**Drawing iOS 7 2D Graphics with Core Graphics**

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Graphics_Tutorial_using_Core_Graphics_and_Core_Image